# Bash script take in parameter or present a select

Tags: bash

We have a script we use to promote databases from dev to QA.  Currently the script has a select statement we use to print out all the available databases and then takes your selection and does the various bits to promote the db.

I want to add a parameter to bypass that select statement for scripting purposes.

Here's how the script works currently:

```
# GET LIST OF DATABASES
DATABASES=`echo "show databases;"|/usr/bin/mysql -u root -h $DEVHOST|grep -v "information_schema"|grep -v "Database"|grep -v "performance_schema"|grep -v "mysql"`

eval set $DATABASES
select DEVDB in "$@"
do
if [[ "$DEVDB" =~ "dev1" ]]; then
  QADB=`echo $DEVDB|sed -e s/_dev1_/_qa1_/`
fi
# Does various bits after this
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
arg1=$1
if [ ! -z "$arg1" ]; then
    DEVDB=$arg1
else
    # GET LIST OF DATABASES
    DATABASES=`echo "show databases;"|/usr/bin/mysql -u root -h $DEVHOST|grep -v "information_schema"|grep -v "Database"|grep -v "performance_schema"|grep -v "mysql"`

    eval set $DATABASES
    select DEVDB in "$@"
    do
fi

if [[ "$DEVDB" =~ "dev1" ]]; then
  QADB=`echo $DEVDB|sed -e s/_dev1_/_qa1_/`
fi
```

I'm getting an error at `fi`, I assume it's related to the `select... do`.  How do I wrap these up in my if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something in the body of the `select`. In this case it's sufficient to check that the variable has a value:

```
PS3="Select a database: "
select DEVDB; do
    [[ $DEVDB ]] && break
done
echo "you selected $DEVDB"
```

Definitely don't need `eval` here -- it's always a code smell.

```
set -- $(
    /usr/bin/mysql -u root -h $DEVHOST <<< "show databases;" |
    grep -v -e information_schema -e Database -e performance_schema -e mysql
)
```